# Text disappearing after CSS fade-in animation?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to set up an animation where a title fades in first and after a delay the subtitle fades in. The title is working fine, but once the subtitle fades in it disappears completely.

It was working fine until I added the delay to the subtitle and now once the subtitle fades in it disappears completely. The best answer I've found is to add `animtion-fill-mode: forwards;` but I've already done that. How can I fix this to have the text stay after fading in?

This is what I have right now:

```
.fade-in-text-sub {
  font-size: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #c1c3d9;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn linear 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn linear 3s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn linear 3s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn linear 3s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn linear 3s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

Comment: Does the answer not fix your issue?

Comment: Please accept answer and/or upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cascading issue. The order in which you declare your animation is being overwritten.
`animation-fill-mode` is definitely the way to go, but adding `animation` after this will overwrite the `fill-mode` back to `none`, since `animation` is a shorthand key, which can contain several properties more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#configuring_the_animation
so you can include `fill-mode` in the same declaration.

For reference I left in the sub title example the `animation-delay` outside of the `animation` property, but since it is set after, it is not reverted back to its default value of `0s`.

```css
.fade-in-text {
  font-size: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #c1c3d9;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
  -o-animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
  animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
}

.fade-in-text-sub {
  font-size: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #c1c3d9;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
  -o-animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
  animation: fadeIn linear 3s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-in-text">fade-in-text</h1>
<h2 class="fade-in-text-sub">fade-in-text-sub</div>
```